# ¿Cómo encontrar ruta de archivo desde un proyecto a otro?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un proyecto que edita los valores de un archivo `properties` que se encuentra en otro proyecto, actualmente funciona pero tengo una ruta estática asi:

Ejemplo:`"C:/Users/dacoso/Documents/proyecto/config/HojaPropiedades.properties"`

Lo que quiero es evitar cambiarle la ruta al archivo cada vez que lo cambie de PC, o tener la facilidad de ejecutarlo en cualquier sistema operativo.

He buscado sobre rutas relativas pero no he encuentrado mucha información.

Comment: Ya intentaste con el getResourceAsStream   this.properties = new Properties();
try {
    properties.load(Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("HojaPropiedades.properties"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que en tus aplicaciones el archivo se encontrará en esta ubicaición:

```
../proyecto/config/HojaPropiedades.properties
```

Podrías crear un objeto `File` y utilizar el método `getAbsolutePath()` el cuál regresa un `String` que representa la ruta real del archivo.

El código para obtener la ruta absoluta, es decir la que mostraría tu directorio de carpetas sería de la siguiente manera:

```
File archivo = new File("config/HojaPropiedades.properties");
System.out.println(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
```

Y la salida sería algo así:

```
"C:/Users/dacoso/Documents/proyecto/config/HojaPropiedades.properties"
```

Espero que esta sea la respuesta que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes optar por asumir que los dos proyectos van a estar ubicados en la misma carpeta. En este caso puedes hacer uso de una ruta relativa para acceder al fichero:

```
../../proyecto/config/HojaPropiedades.properties
```

La desventaja de esta solución está en su rigidez. En cuanto no respetes la regla de adyacencia la ruta no será válida.

Otra posibilidad es recurrir a las variables de entorno para almacenar la ruta de acceso:

```
RutaProyecto=C:/Users/dacoso/Documents/proyecto/config/HojaPropiedades.properties
```

Y para acceder a dicha variable:

```
System.getenv("RutaProyecto");
```

La desventaja de esta solución es que la variable tienes que crearla manualmente (o programar una aplicación que la genere por ti).

Una última posibilidad que se me ocurre pasa por crear un acceso directo. En este caso podrías acceder al fichero mediante dicho acceso directo sin importar la ubicación de cada proyecto.

Comment: Crees que si consulto/investigo  algo sobre CLASSPATH pueda encontrar el camino hacia mi respuesta??

Comment: @Dacoso Hasta donde se, `CLASSPATH` sirve para indicar la ubicación de los archivos a compilar y ejecutar... dado que tu estás haciendo modificaciones sobre otro proyecto yo diría que no te va a funcionar, pero esto último estaría bien que alguien más ducho en Java lo confirmase.

Comment: @Dacoso También has de tener presente que nadie mejor que tu para saber cuán específica debe ser la solución a aplicar. Si siempre se van a ver implicados los dos mismos proyectos puede ser más sencillo encontrar una solución a medida.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podría ser que cuando se inicia la aplicación se copie el fichero en una ruta común en cualquier computadora. 
Por ejemplo lo podrías colocar el. C://tuproyecto/tu archivo.

Comment: No todos los Sistemas Operativos manejan unidades con letras. Salvo esto puede usarse por ejemplo el directorio inicial del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: Pero eso me arrojara el directorio desde donde lanzo la aplicación, lo que en si necesito es la ruta del archivo el cual quiero editar.

Comment: ¿no se puede considerar una ruta relativa al directorio donde se lanzo la aplicación?